# Origin http://localhost:3000 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin in Rails 3 application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xmlhttprequest, cross-domain, cors

I can't get GET from XHR by following Error

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://blog.rrikesh.com/demo/assets/img/img1.jpg. Origin       
http://localhost:3000 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

So, I allowed cross domain access like this :

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
  before_filter :allow_cross_domain_access
  def allow_cross_domain_access
      response.headers["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "*"
      response.headers["Access-Control-Allow-Methods"] = "GET, PUT, POST, DELETE"
  end
end
```

But, it occurs same error. What can I do?

Comment: Have you considered JSONP? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP

Comment: Can you show the JavaScript you are using to make the request? It could be that your JS code is sending some custom headers. Sometimes, the following will fix things: `response.headers["Access-Control-Allow-Headers"] = "Content-Type"`

Comment: I'm using this jQuery library to access EXIF data. http://www.nihilogic.dk/labs/exifjquery/jquery.exif.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following PHP code works for me.
Note that the if (...) are very important, if you returns the same CORES header for all request then (at least) chrome will cancel request (for at least localhost server)

```
<?php
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {
    //header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']}");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');    
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS"); 
}   
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD']))
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS");         
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']))
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']}");

    exit(0);
}
```

?>